# How to set the expiry time of an applications token to -1 for WSO2 APIM 2.1.0?

Tags: api, oauth, wso2, token, wso2-api-manager

I have tried creating a new application and setting the expiry time to -1 on the UI for the store which looks like it worked based on what I saw on the UI. However when I tried a curl to get a token it defaulted to 3600 seconds still.

I then looked into it and found another way in which I can edit the identity.xml default to be -1 and restart WSO2. Apparently that is supposed to change it for all new applications and leave existing ones as is. So I did that and created a second new application. Again the UI looked like it was working but when I did the curl for the token it was still 3600 seconds.

Please could someone tell me if I am missing something or have done something wrong. I need to create just one application that has a token that never expires ( or at least lasts an extremely long time )

Thanks

Comment: can you share the curl command you used to generate the token? also, what is the configuration, you edited in identity.xml?

Comment: This is the command I used:

curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=device_ipad" -H "Authorization :Basic base64encode(consumer-key:consumer-secret), Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token

And this is the config I edited in the Identity.xml:

<UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>3800</UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>

Answer (score 0):

When generating the Token from the Store UI, the API Manager uses the Client Credentials grant to generate the Access Tokens (explicitly passing the validity period).

As per the shared comment, you are trying to generate an access token using the Password Grant. In such a scenario, we can perform the following configurations ([Doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens-Changingthedefaulttokenexpirationtime)) to generate the User access token with an infinite lifetime

- Configure the `identity.xml` to configure newly created applications with an infinite token span

  - As you have already performed, update the `UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod` value in the `<apim>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` with larger values (example: 9223372036854775) to generate a long-lasting token

    ```xml
    <UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>9223372036854775</UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>
    ```
  - Once the configurations are made, please do restart the API Manager node to take effect on the changes and try the scenario again with the Password Grant with a new Application

Hope this helps to achieve your requirement

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this as well as the -1 and same result. New tokens are still set to 3600 seconds expiry

Comment: Can you share the following information. Is only a single node API-M is deployed in your environment? Or are you having a distributed setup? Were you able to create a new Application and test the scenario as well?

Comment: There is only a single node. And I was able to create the new application, on the store it mentioned the expiry time was as I set it but when I generated a token using a curl it was 3600 seconds still

Comment: I was able to generate the Tokens successfully in the APIM 2.1.0 GA pack. Just to confirm, can you share whether you changed the Basic Auth Header in the cURL command with the correct Consumer Credentials of the new Application and generated the Token? And I believe you are using the GA release and no patches or updates were applied in the API Manager. Can you share the values set to both `AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod`, and `UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod` in the `identity.xml`?